# ExtJS - Send custom header when using sync

Tags: extjs, http-headers, store

When using a store sync method is it possible to send custom headers to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra headers to the underlying **proxy** which will be used when a `sync` method is executed. For example you can configure your store like this:

```
Ext.define('MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
        url: '/api/v1...'
    }
});
```

...and your model like this:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
        url : '/api/v1...'
    }
});
```